# Query does not run when using mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm converting an old script to be compliant with MySQLi and ran in to an issue...

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit();
} 

$myQuery = "INSERT INTO table (name, description) VALUES ('$name', '$description')";

if (!mysqli_query($link, $myQuery)) {
    printf('Error');
} else {
    printf('Success');
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

This works fine, no errors. But when I add the mysqli_real_escape_string() I get an error...

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit();
} 

$myQuery = "INSERT INTO table (name, description) VALUES ('$name', '$description')";

$myQuery = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $myQuery);

if (!mysqli_query($link, $myQuery)) {
    printf('Error');
} else {
    printf('Success');
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

This returns an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\'TestName\', \'TestDescription\' at line 1

Am I missing something simple? Quotes?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is for escaping string values, not the whole SQL query. -- Read up on parameter binding instead. And after you figured out why that's more effort with mysqli, just switch to PDO.

Comment: @mario Just a quick note in case you may have seen my answer after you posted your comment. It was not based on what you posted in your comment, as I was already typing it out. It was purely coincidental.

Comment: @James. I'm not sure if you saw my answer or not, but I've made an edit and you will need to reload it, in order to see what I modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$myQuery = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $myQuery);
```

That isn't right.

You need to use `$name` variable and not the `$myQuery` variable. That's what need escaping and not the whole query itself.

```
$myQuery = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name);
```

However, ^ `$myQuery` should be replaced with each of the variables being used to be inserted.

Your query should look more like this:

```
$name = "TestName";
$description = "TestDescription";

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $description);

$myQuery = "INSERT INTO `table` (name, description) VALUES ('$name', '$description')";

if (!mysqli_query($link, $myQuery)) {
    printf('Error');
} else {
    printf('Success');
}
```

---

Nota:

You may want to look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Plus, just for argument's sake; `table` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) should that be the actual table's name and is required to be escaped:

```
$myQuery = "INSERT INTO `table`
```

- Just an insight.

---

An example of a `mysqli` prepared statement:

```
$variable_1 = "Text";
$variable_2 = "More text";

$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name 
                        (column_1, column_2) 
                        VALUES (?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $variable_1, $variable_2);
$stmt->execute();
```

- Sidenote: `s` is for strings

---

An example of a PDO prepared statement:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_DB', $user, $pass);

$var_1 = "Text";
$var_2 = "More text";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name 
                       (column_1, column_2) 
                       VALUES (:var_1,:var_2)");

$stmt->execute(array(':var_1' => $var_1, ':var_2' => $var_2));
```

Comment: I'd assume both $name and $description are just preset above the sample code. Looks all like tutorial values and code.

Comment: @mario I'd assume also, but I wanted to make sure and to let the OP know.