# Can I use mysql_real_escape_string function by passing the whole MySQL query as parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

I am working on securing a huge existing application against SQL injection. It is very old and it is close to impossible to refactor, due to the use of the famous "copy/paste" pattern development model. All select queries parameters (which come from user input) are not being filtered. However there is a custom query function that is being used. It accepts MySQL query as parameter and executes it against the database. It looks like this:

```
    public function query($sql) {
        $this->m_query_id = @mysql_query($sql, $this->m_link_id);
    ...
    }
```

My question is, will a modification like this:

```
    public function query($sql) {
        $sql = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);//escaping the whole SQL query
        $this->m_query_id = @mysql_query($sql, $this->m_link_id);
    ...
    }
```

work at all, or it will potentially make the queries break or return false data?

Example **$sql** value would be any simple or complex SELECT query, but for the sake of the example lets say it looks like this:

```
SELECT customer_id as customerID 
FROM customers 
WHERE user_email LIKE '%some-sample-email_98@domain.com%' 
AND user_name LIKE '%La'tanya%'
AND date_registered > '2015-01-01 22:33:53'
```

Comment: No you can't,nor should you.... that will escape any quotes around string literals (such as those around `'%some-sample-email_98@domain.com%' `), which you don't want to do.... the best way to work with SQL isn't to escape values anyway, it's to use bind variables with prepared statements..... even if that is extra work

Comment: @MarkBaker you should post this as an answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query does not run when using mysqli\_real\_escape\_string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29358321)

Comment: Do not use the error-suppressing `@` operator unless you have an exceptionally good reason. YOLO programming is not cool.

Comment: Getting rid of all that code and replacing it with some sane prepared statements with placeholder values would fix this issue. I'd suggest using PDO at an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mark Baker:

> No you can't,nor should you.... that will escape any quotes around string literals (such as those around '%some-sample-email_98@domain.com%' ), which you don't want to do.... the best way to work with SQL isn't to escape values anyway, it's to use bind variables with prepared statements..... even if that is extra work